# Mocha/Chai/ChaiAsPromised : expect(promise).eventually not waiting for resolution

Tags: javascript, promise, mocha.js, chai, chai-as-promised

I've got a function I want to test. It returns a promise. Here'a fake version that just waits a bit and then resolves the promise.

```
function testee(){
    let myPromise = new Promise(
        (resolve, reject) => {
            setTimeout( () => {               
                resolve( 777 );
            }, 1000);
        }
     );
 
    return myPromise;
}
```

I'm using Mocha, Chai and ChaiAsPromised, and I try to test using eventually, thinking this will wait for the promise to resolve. I'm deliberately writing a test that should fail, and it passes. Why?

```
var chai = require('chai')  ;
var chaiAsPromised = require("chai-as-promised");
var expect = chai.expect;
chai.use(chaiAsPromised);

describe("Testing Promises", function() {
    it("should return a particular value ", function() {

     const testPromise = testee();

     // no matter what I specify in the equal it always passes the test
     expect(testPromise).to.eventually.equal(490);
});
```

I'm aware there are other ways to manage asynch processing under Mocha, or to avoid using Promises, but I want to understand why my tests don't fail as I would expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the assertion statement is asynchronous code, you should return the assertion statement so that `mocha` will know that it should wait for this function to be called to complete the test.

Please read the [doc](https://www.chaijs.com/plugins/chai-as-promised/) about `chai-as-promised` and [asynchronous-code](https://mochajs.org/#asynchronous-code) of `mocha`.

```js
const { testee } = require('.');
var chai = require('chai');
var chaiAsPromised = require('chai-as-promised');
var expect = chai.expect;
chai.use(chaiAsPromised);

describe('Testing Promises', function () {
  it('should return a particular value ', function () {
    const testPromise = testee();
    return expect(testPromise).to.eventually.equal(777);
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you, I had somehow missed the very clearly documented need to return when using expect.

Comment: alternatively if you are using async/await, you can just make the inner function async then `await expect(testPromise).to.eventually.equal(777)`